# Access Actual File Name

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

For some file name encoding concerns (users in Spain) and some other concerns, we need to manually structure the file name for the uploaded file.

When Fine Uploader passes the information to the server, the code changes the target filename (in the use case below, to "my_name.jpg").  The handler.php file saves the file with that name to the file system, then returns that new file name in the uploadName parameter.  This is all working properly.

When I return that information to Fine Uploader via the uploadName parameter, I'm expecting to be able to access that new file name in javascript, so that I can then make calls to store the file name to a database.

The relevant code is below:

Settings:

```
 var settings = {
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'ajax/endpoint.php',
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: 'ajax/endpoint.php'
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
            this.setName(id, response.uploadName);
        }
    }, 
    autoUpload: true,
    editFilename: false,
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: false
    },
    session: {
        endpoint: 'ajax/initialfiles.php'
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
        itemLimit: 3,
        sizeLimit: 5000000
    }
};
```

Code:

```
$uploaderDiv = $('#fine-uploader');

uploaderObj = $uploaderDiv.fineUploader(settings).on("statusChange", function (event, id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
    if (newStatus == 'upload successful' || newStatus == 'deleted') {
        var files = uploaderObj.fineUploader('getUploads');
        $.each(files, function (i, file) {
            if (file.status == 'upload successful') {
                console.log(file);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When uploading a file, the response from the server is:

```
{"success":true,"uuid":"f542c893-920a-4f58-a57f-7bd5d0f45294","uploadName":"my_name-715.jpg"}
```

However, the console log for the file info generates:

```
{
batchId: "98b6a0c0-28ed-466f-8d69-9cea425c20a9"
id: 0
name: "Karen_Book (thumb).jpg",
originalName: "Karen_Book (thumb).jpg",
proxyGroupId: "acf40500-9c8b-4c6e-a4f6-2542443d458d",
size: 5977
status: "upload successful",
uuid: "f542c893-920a-4f58-a57f-7bd5d0f45294"
}
```

Given the scenario above, how can I get the filename "my_name-715.jpg" in the statusChange event?

Comment: I don't understand the question, or what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to change the name of the file? Simply returning an `uploadName` in your response will not achieve this.

Comment: @RayNicholus - When the file name comes back from the ajax call, I need to get access to the actual file name that was saved, so that I can then store that information in the database.  I'll expand the question.

Comment: @cale_b Try saving file as base64 string within JSON object . User could input file name , or file name could be set at `js` ; preserving same file name  throughout process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like access to any response from your server, you must do so inside [an `onComplete` event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete). The response JSON is included as a parameter passed to your handler. It sounds like you want to make an request to your server with the updated name (from your server?). In that same handler, you should send whatever request is required. `onComplete` fires when the upload request completes, and `onDeleteComplete` fires when a delete request completes.

Comment: Hi Ray - thank you.  If you look at my code sample, I've got an oncomplete handler.  Are you saying I need to maintain a separate variable with this data? Using (for example) the uuid as the key / connection between my data and the data available in the getUploads call?

Comment: Are you saying that the `setName` function is not actually changing the file name? I'm not seeing any such issue. If this is not the issue, then _why_ do you want to access this new file name in the statusChange handler? Most likely the status is changed to success before onComplete is called.

Comment: Ray - I need to save the file name to a database after the file is successfully uploaded.  How else would you suggest I go about this?  setName is setting the name for the front-end display, but does not make the name available (that I can see) anywhere else?

Comment: Do this in your onComplete handler, or on the server as part of handling the upload request.

Comment: Ray - That makes sense - except I need a complete list of files - after upload, deletion, etc - the full list of files.  Does the onComplete handler fire on a delete also? (I need to know if / when a delete is performed as well)?  If it does, I should be able to make that work.  (for a couple reasons, I can't do it in the handler).

Comment: The [`onDeleteComplete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#deleteComplete) fires when a file delete attempt has completed (though not necessarily succeeded). See the docs for more details. The behavior of `onComplete` is also documented on this same page.